# Why is the Visual Studio Code terminal not working internally?

Tags: terminal, visual-studio-code

The Visual Studio Code terminal is not working as an integrated terminal, but as I click *New Terminal*, it opens `cmd.exe` as an external tool.

I tried checking the settings, but it was integrated as before, but yet the problem is still there.

I am getting this message:

> The terminal process terminated with exit code: 3221225786

Comment: This was around the same time (though this was posted prior) as [Windows 10 Insider Preview Build 18945](https://blogs.windows.com/windows-insider/2019/07/26/announcing-windows-10-insider-preview-build-18945/). A coincidence?

Comment: Was it on Windows?

Answer (score 8):

I have the exact same problem, and I am pretty sure I have not made any relevant changes...

In the meantime, I’ve found a temporary fix or at least it works for me: go to settings and search for "conpty", in the "terminal → integrated: Windows enable ConPTY" section uncheck the "whether to use ConPTY..." and the integrated terminal works as before.

It looks like it is a bug: *[Terminal is always launching externally when ConPTY is turned on #73790](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/73790)*

Comment: Thanks it worked completely fine now . It was probably due to new windows 10 update

Answer (score 0):

Turn off the checkbox "Windows Enable ConPTY".
This is highly recommended for error exit code '3221225794' when I open the terminal in Visual Studio Code.